# Wrapping divs based on a dynamic class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Take the following HTML for example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="body">Content</div>
<div class="body">Content</div>
<div class="body">Content</div>
<div class="header">Content</div>
<div class="header">Content</div>
<div class="header">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Content</div>
</div>
```

What result I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="tabarea">
<div class="body">Content</div>
<div class="body">Content</div>
<div class="body">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="tabarea">
<div class="header">Content</div>
<div class="header">Content</div>
<div class="header">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="tabarea">
<div class="footer">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Content</div>
</div>

</div>
```

I've already searched for hours through several topics and have also tried several jQuery combinations(to no avail though), like:

```
$('.container div').each(function(){
      $(this).wrap('<div class="tabarea"></div>');
    });
```

But this selects every div listed above and wraps in a tabarea classed div.

I know I could probably list each class individually, but there will likely be more added in the future. And it has to be done on the client side because the HTML is generated after the tab interface I'm using is called (jQuery UI tabs).

Basically, I'm stuck on how to choose the multiple class selectors at once to start the function.

Comment: Try $('div.container').each(....), I'm not pro at jQuery but it may help, as then you will be selecting all div's with the class of 'container'. Give it a try :)

Comment: Hi DarkMantis, tried that and it didn't even seem to pick up the divs that were already there (IE no wrapper divs showed up)

Comment: Ah fair enough, I thought it'd be worth a try though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var classes = [];

$('div.container div').each(function() {
    var cssClass = $(this).attr('class');
    if ($.inArray(cssClass, classes) == -1)
        classes.push(cssClass);
});

var i = classes.length;
while (i--) {
    $('div.' + classes[i]).wrapAll('<div class="tabarea"></div>');
}
```

This will built a list of all the individual classes and then wrap each group (assuming they're next to each other)

http://jsfiddle.net/PCXvb/2/

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's possible to list all those classes individually, but there's going to be a bunch more classes (probably a few hundred) that will need to be wrapped in a similar fashion, which is why I was hoping there was a dynamic solution I may have overlooked.

Comment: @James Np, the updated solution in JNDPNTs answer will also work, not sure which is faster though.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
var container = $('<div class="tabarea"></div>')
                    .insertBefore('.container div.body:first');
$('.container div.body').appendTo(container);
```

and you can extend it for multiple selectors:

```
var container = $('<div class="tabarea"></div>');
var selectors = [
    ".container div.body",
    ".container div.header",
    ".container div.footer"
];
$.each(selectors,function(i,selector){
    var el = $(selector);
    var c = container
        .clone()
        .insertBefore(el.eq(0));
    el.appendTo(c);
});
```

**UPDATE** : [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/EaETR/)

Comment: That does wrap the first class list, but that's all it wraps.

Comment: Hi Gion, thanks for the looking into it, yeah that does work for the code I posted above, but I needed a dynamic solution, as there's going to be many more tabareas with more classes added to the script.

Answer (score 0):

It's to simple...

```
$('.container div').each(function()
{
    // Make sure this div isn't already inside a tabarea div
    if (!$(this).parent('.tabarea').length) {
        // Call wrapAll to wrap all divs of this class
        $("div." + $(this).attr("class")).wrapAll('<div class="tabarea"></div>');
    }
});
```

This will dynamically read what your had but instead of wrapping everything, it will take the div's class and select all div elements with that class. Therefore it will offer you a fast and dynamic solution. However you can probably improve it (it will now do it to much as it executes this for every div in the container)

Comment: Doesn't quite work - http://jsfiddle.net/PCXvb/3/ Also, you wanted  `$(this).attr("class")` rather than `this.attr("class")`.

Comment: Strange, this did work for me... Apparently not anymore. I probably changed something an forgot to hit update. :/

Comment: Hi JNDPNT, just tried the code above, but it seems to wrap all the inner divs with the class as well (I had other divs inside as well, where it says "Content" in my OP), sorry if that code wasn't that clear.